# How to pass an id to a view as an argument in Django?

Tags: django, django-views

I am learning Django and at the moment I am at a really basic level.

In this project, I am building a minimal cart app, and so far I have managed to display on the homepage some items and the relative price. I would rather, if possible to not use sessions for this project.

I have now added an 'add' link next to each item in the list so that when the user clicks on it, that item will be added to the cart. (I was trying to do the same with an 'add' button but as far as I understood that implies the creation of a form, which will be my next issue to tackle.)

I would like to display everything (menu items and cart summary) on the homepage.

The newly created 'add_to_cart' view function takes in a request and an item and returns the request, the same HTML as home, and as the context, the 'cart_items' variable.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to pass the item id, in order to 'get' that item in the query and then add it to the cart.

The code I have produced so far is the following.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# Create your models here.
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Order number: %s' % self.id
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from .models import Cart, Item
from django.db.models import Sum


# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    items = Item.objects.all()
    carts = Cart.objects.all()
    length = len(Cart.objects.all())
    cart = carts[length - 1]
    cart_items = cart.items.all()
    total = cart_items.aggregate(Sum('price'))['price__sum']
    return render(request, 'cart/home.html', {'cart': cart,
                                              'items': items,
                                              'cart_items': cart_items,
                                              'total': total})


def add_to_cart(request, item):
    item = Item.objects.get(id=item)
    carts = Cart.objects.all()
    length = len(Cart.objects.all())
    cart = carts[length - 1]
    cart_items = cart.items.add(item)
    return render(request,  'cart/home.html', {'cart_items': cart_items})
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('add/', views.add_to_cart, name='add_to_cart')
]
```

home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div><h1>Menu</h1></div>
{% for item in items %}
<ul>{{ item }} £{{ item.price}} <a href="add/">Add</a></ul>
{% endfor %}
<div><h1>Order</h1></div>S
{{ cart }}
{% for item in cart_items %}
    <ul>{{ item.name }} {{ item.price }}</ul>
{% endfor %}
<h2>Total</h2>
{{ total|floatformat }}
</body>
</html>
```

The error I get when clicking on the 'add' link is, of course, the following:

TypeError at /add/
add_to_cart() missing 1 required positional argument: 'item'

Comment: You add it to the `path(..)`

Comment: I am trying to make it work but this is definitely the right 'way'. Thanks, as soon as it's sorted I will post the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

urls.py

```
    path('add/<int:item>', views.add_to_cart, name='add_to_cart')
```

home.html

```
{% for item in items %}
  <ul>{{ item }} £{{ item.price}} <a href="{% url 'add_to_cart' item.id %}">Add</a></ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That's it. Thanks :) is it this the only way to pass the item id in 'href'?

Comment: Yes, that's a Django way.

Answer (score 0):

For class Based View :

If Path in the `urls.py` contains

```
path('products/<int:pk>', views.ProductRetriveUpdateAPI.as_view())
```

then `View.py` looks like this

```
Class ProductUpdateRetrieViewAPI(generics.ProductRetriveUpdateAPI):
    
    def get_queryset():
        product_id = self.kwargs['pk']
```