# How to resolve "NoReverseMatch" Error in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

So I'm trying to create a table of hosts, and as one of the fields of that table include a clickable link to an update page. Which will pass the host_id to the update page. I was hoping someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong with regards to passing the correct parameter to upate/<host_id>. As I'm not quite sure as to how to fix the issue and make it so I can direct people via a clickable button in the table rendered to the appropriate update page. When I attempt to render the page with that added in I'm getting the following error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /website/home/
Reverse for 'update' with arguments '(1,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['website/update/<host_id>']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/website/home/
Django Version: 4.0.4
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'update' with arguments '(1,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['website/update/<host_id>']
```

It is also spiecificlly pointing to the following line of code as the issue:

```
 <td><a href="{% url 'update' beacon.host_id %}"</a>Issue Command</td>
```

This line is found in the following HTML segment.
**Relevant HTML Section**

```
 {% for beacon in hosts %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ beacon.host_id }}</td>
            <td>{{ beacon.hostname }}</td>
            <td>{{ beacon.internalIp }}</td>
            <td>{{ beacon.externalIp }}</td>
            <td>{{ beacon.current_user }}</td>
            <td>{{ beacon.os }}</td>
            <td>{{ beacon.admin }}</td>
            <td><a href="{% url 'update' beacon.host_id %}"</a>Issue Command</td>
        </tr>
            {% endfor %}
```

My urls.py section looks like the following.
**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path('home/', views.home),
    re_path('host-detailed', views.host_detailed),
    re_path('update/<host_id>', views.update, name='update'),
]
```

**Relevant Models.py**

```
class Command_Node(models.Model):
    host_id = models.ForeignKey(Beacon, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    current_commands = models.CharField(
        choices=CHOICES, max_length=50, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.host_id)
```

**Relevant Views.py**

```
def home(request):
    hosts = Beacon.objects.all()
    return render (request, 'home.html', {'hosts':hosts})

def host_detailed(request):
    return render (request, 'hosts-detailed.html')


def update(request, host_id):
    host_id = Command_Node.objects.get(pk=host_id)
    form = Command_Node(request.POST or None, instance=host_id)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('home.html')
    return render (request, 'update.html', {'host_id':host_id,'form':form})
```

Comment: Should you be using `path` instead of `re_path` in your urlpatterns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:
Urls:

```
  path('update/<int:pk>',views.update,name='update'),
```

Template

```
href="{% url 'update' pk = beacon.host_id %}"
```

As the other comment also mentioned, I don't think re_path is the way to go

[How to pass an id to a view as an argument in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59842406/how-to-pass-an-id-to-a-view-as-an-argument-in-django)